# ¿Como obtengo el View en un Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, nullpointerexception, jvm

Estoy empezando a programar en Android con Kotlin y estoy algo confuso con los Null Safety.

El problema principal viene al querer hacer un findViewById a partir del getView() (view en kotlin) en un fragment, he estado consultado y solo he encontrado la siguiente forma:

```
 fun setUpRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)
    mAdapter.RecyclerAdapter(getMeals(), this.activity!!)
    mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
}
```

En teoria si no me equivoco con view?.findViewById obtengo el view de la Activity enlazada a este fragment.

Aunque el IDE me obliga a poner el ? delante del view y cuando intenta obtener el RecyclerView me da el siguiente error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.chdzma.changeproject, PID: 29649
>                     kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>                         at com.chdzma.changeproject.fragments.Meals.setUpRecyclerView(MealsFragment.kt:51)
>                         at com.chdzma.changeproject.fragments.Meals.onCreate(MealsFragment.kt:47)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2331)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1386)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1188)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1071)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:115)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2380)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

He estado buscando en kotlin pero no encuentro la forma de que me funcione ni la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta que al momento de hace el casting, el compilador interpreta que el cast sera un objeto no nulo:

```
view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView) 
  as
     RecyclerView; //<-- No esta marcado como nullable por lo que si retorna null, lanza el error
```

Utiliza el operador de casteo seguro [`as?`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) para evitar el error:

```
//...
 mRecyclerView = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView) as? RecyclerView
///
```